# Extract position and rotation of arrows in streamplot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a streamplot like this

```
elField1P[q1_, {x1_, y1_}][x_, y_] := Module[{r1t},
r1t = {x - x1, y - y1};
q1 Normalize[r1t]/Norm[r1t]];

startingPoints = CirclePoints[{-1, 0}, 0.1, 20]~Join~CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 0.1, 18][[{4, 6}]];

g = StreamPlot[elField1P[2, {-1, 0}][x, y] + elField1P[-1, {1, 0}][x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, StreamPoints -> {startingPoints, Automatic, Scaled[1]}, StreamStyle -> {Red, "Line"}, StreamScale -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotRangePadding -> None,ImageSize -> 600, Epilog -> Point[startingPoints]] ;

(* Add arrows in the middle of field lines *)
gf = Normal[g] /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{{0.02, 0.5}}], Arrow[x]}
```

Which ouput this plot

[image: streamplot]

Now I would like to extract the position of the arrows in the plot and I don't know how to do it. This command

```
arrows = Cases[gf, Arrow[__], 7]
```

gives a list of the arrows in the form

```
{Arrow[{{x1, y1},{x2, y2},...}],...}
```

but it doesn't tell me where the tips of the arrows are. I could use the information in two ways:
- position and rotation of the arrow tip
or
- starting and ending point (they have to be very close if the field is not  straight in that region) of the straight segment the arrow lies on.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `LineScaledCoordinate` from the `` "GraphUtilities`" `` package as follows:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
tips = Cases[gf, Arrow[x_, ___] :> LineScaledCoordinate[x, .5], All];
Show[gf, Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Large], Point @ tips}]]
```

[image]

**Note:** Using `StreamStyle -> {Red, Arrowheads[{{0.02, .5}}],"Arrow"}` in defining `g` you get the desired output without having to pos-process.

Comment: That's good, this gives me the position of the tips but what about the orientation? Is there a way to find also the point before? I need to plot those arrow tips using small straight segments like (startingPoint)-(endPoint), or, (point) and rotation.

Comment: @Emmet, You can use `LineScaledCoordinate[x, #]&/@{.5-delta,.5,.5+delta}` for small `delta` to get three points (before the tip, at the tip and after the tip)

Comment: I tried `tips = Cases[gf, 
  Arrow[x_, ___] :> LineScaledCoordinate[x, #] & /@ {.5 - 
     delta, .5, .5 + delta}, All]` but it gives me an empty list.

Comment: @Emmet, try `delta =.05; tips = Cases[gf, Arrow[x_, ___] :> (LineScaledCoordinate[x, #] & /@ {.5 - delta, .5, .5 + delta}), All]`?

Comment: Now it works, thank you very much.